# Is it possible to add values to SESSION w/ jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form with many rows of items, each line with checkbox that has item's ID.

I need to take item ID and add it to php $_SESSION when a single checkbox or all checkboxes selected (REMOVE FROM SESSION IF UNCHECKED). Currently I have the following code to select all checkboxes:

```
var checkboxes = $(".chkbx").change(function() {
    var allIsChecked = checkboxes.length === checkboxes.filter(":checked").length;
    all[0].checked = allIsChecked;
    enableMyElement(checkboxes.filter(":checked").length > 0);
    putInSession($(this).val());
});
var all = $("#checkall").change(function() {
    checkboxes.attr("checked",this.checked);
    enableMyElement(this.checked);
});

function putInSession(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: actions.php,
        type: "POST",
        data: "action=addToSession&ID="+id;                 
    });
}   

<input id="checkall" type="checkbox">
<input class="chkbx" type="checkbox" value="360" name="delCont[]">
<input class="chkbx" type="checkbox" value="500" name="delCont[]">
<input class="chkbx" type="checkbox" value="510" name="delCont[]">
```

How do I update my PHP session with jQuery? Is it even possible? What are the alternatives?

---

UPDATE:

OK, Ajax is clearly the way to go. Added new function putInSession(). Still not clear how to integrate with my SelectAll fnctionality...

Comment: Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ajax to call a script to add the item id to the session

Comment: Oh, that's a great idea. How would I add that to my current jQuery functionality?

Comment: add `oncheck="function(id)"` to your check box and create a function that passes an id to the script you are calling via POST and then do your session assignment there.

Comment: OK, how would I add the values of all checked checkboxes, when I select them all by selecting #checkall?

Comment: then you would have an extra function that gets all of the checkboxes by the class and then loop through passing in their ids to the script

Answer (score 1):

Like others have stated use jQuery [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Have a look [here](http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/07/beginners-guide-to-using-ajax-with-jquery/) for a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Call a PHP script through ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'script.php',
    data: {
        session_var : 'bla_bla_bla'
    }
});
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: You want { session_var : 'bla_bla_bla' } and not { session_var = 'bla_bla_bla'}